# Does using an Iterator over a TreeMap in Java interfere with the order of keys?

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

I want to know that if using an Iterator over a TreeMap in Java interfere with the order of keys?

Comment: Why would it? What are you trying to do? Iterating on the keys, or the values? In any case, I don't see why it would interfere.

Comment: @Savino over the keys. but anyhow I cant find the .iterator() for in the TreeMap class! :(

Comment: see answers below, you want to call the keySet() method then, and it returns them sorted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet%28%29) :

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order.

If for some reason you need the keys in descending order, you can use [`descendingKeySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingKeySet%28%29)

If you want to iterate over the values, you can use [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet%28%29)

(Wow, I didn't know that `Map` isn't a `Collection` before...)

Answer (score 4):

No - it will iterate in the order defined by the `TreeMap`, i.e. the natural ordering of the keys, or the one imposed by the comparator specified in the constructor. Just iterating won't change that in the underlying tree map, either.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't interfere. It gives you keys in ascending order.

Iterator using `entrySet`

[From official docs - entrySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet%28%29)

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
```

Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set's iterator returns the entries in **ascending key order**.